# Problema com css desde que foi mudado o site para https

Tags: html, css

Boa noite,

Eu tinha o site todo em HTTP agora mudei para HTTPS para aumentar a segurança e os dados dos nossos utilizadores o que me está acontecer e que estou a ter um problema de css só na primeira pagina em HTTP aparecia bem mas agora desde que mudei para HTTPS quebrou o css na pagina inicial de resto esta a funcionar bem não sei o que possa ser ?

Podem ver o problema no site

https://www.sabeonde.pt

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: eu estou conseguindo acessar normalmente. onde esta o erro? mostra um print screen

Comment: Ja colquei o botoes sao centrados e encontra-nos no facebook leva uma caixa com fundo branco e nao esta a funcionar o problema e so ai de resto esta bom

Comment: Mas pra acessar essa pagina tem que fazer login? nao tem como desabilitar por agora so pra teste?

Comment: faça login se nao quiser ficar registado eu removo depois o seu user

Comment: Ja fiz usando email so que a pagina fica carregando, parece loop infinito ate agora nao parou

Comment: Demorou mais de 2 minutos, mas abriu vou ver aqui...

Comment: Não querendo ser chato, mas aparentemente o botão de login via Google não funcionou. Achei a proposta interessante, fiz meu cadastro pelo método tradicional. Mas mesmo dessa forma, demorou uns 2 minutos para abrir a página.

Comment: Tenho de ver o que esta a causa isso mas agora queria resolver esse problema do css que nao estou a ver o que seja

Comment: @CésarSousa o CSS aqui aparece normal. Não vejo nenhuma falha no seu CSS. Tente acessar de outro browser, limpar o cache do navegador e dar um flush dns.

Comment: Mas aparece no os botoes e o encontra-nos no facebook aparece bem ou aparece como o print ?

Comment: Compreeendo. Aqui ainda aparece como print. Poderia colocar estes detalhes na sua pergunta?

Comment: Tente colocar a url completa com https na inclusao dos scripts e do css <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.sabeonde.pt/css/style.css" />

Comment: tentei nao resoveu o mais estranho e que e so isso que esta aparecer mal desde que comecei a usar https

Comment: nao vi nada aqui continua o mesmo sem https. coloca de novo.

Comment: esta a carregar como https

Comment: Já resolvi acabei criando uma class nova para essa situaçao